# Can my employer see my phone browsing history on my work desktop?

Tags: privacy, google

What if I logged in to my work PC using my personal Google account?

Can my employer see what I have been googling on my phone under my work desktop's browsing history? What about under “my activity” in Google? Would it be auto synced?

Simply put, I logged in to my work PC and personal mobile using the same Google account. So would my private searches done using my phone be available on my work PC?

Comment: It will depend on what is synced to the work PC. And it depends on what kinds of tools your employer uses to monitor company PCs.

Comment: Sorry, how do i check what is synced to my work PC? All i know is i used my personal google account to login my work desktop's chrome browser. So would my phone browsing history be accessible to my employer as i made the mistake of logging in my work PC using my personal google account? :(

Comment: We can at most tell you what would be technically possible. But if your employer is actually doing everything possible s unknown to us. Note that lack of interest, costs, time and laws might actually prevent the employer doing this.

Comment: I have reasonable doubt to think that my employer has done this and also looked at my lync conversation history. Lync is company property, so I don't mind. But my phone browsing history is extremely personal and i would never want my employer to see it or have access to it. But you are telling me it's possible because i made the mistake of logging in my work PC using my personal google account. :(

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in some comments, this will depend on the setup your employer has on the pc and in the network you are working on. You are in your rights to be concerned about your privacy and we all should always keep an eye in the correct use of personal data even if it's something simple as our search results and youtube video history.

If your gmail accounts are synchronized in the browser, all your synchronized settings will be in all of your devices. If you are just logged in, you will need to access account settings and view history from there. This means that whoever has 'physical' access to a device with your account can see your activity. This does not mean that your employer has access to it even if that info is on the work computer, unless he walks to the computer and uses it.

But there are malicious ways to gain more information or access to your accounts like a remote monitoring tool. If your work pc has a remote tool, then he can get access to the PC remotely and view your stuff since the accounts are already logged in.

Another way can be to have a keylogger installed in the background and everything you type will be recorded by the employer. They can get passwords and other information from you.

Another malicious way is that the network has some type of proxy (mitm) which all network traffic goes through. This way they can get your password, cookies or any other useful stuff. This way they can impersonate you on a different device and gain access to your account.

So if you want to be 100 percent sure you are not being monitored, check all your account settings, your connected devices, check for malicious software and backdoors in the pc... Then use a VPN when you are at work.

Answer (score -1):

If they steal your login password via something like Mimikatz, yes, they could see your search activities unless you use 2FA authentication, always set it to not remember your working laptop/PC after you login successfully and you always login in Incognito mode of your browser.

Comment: I never logged out of my work PC until just recently. This is a serious intrusion of my privacy. It's appalling that they're able to snoop around like this. Whatever i Google in my phone is none of their business. But they have access to it because i logged in my work PC using my personal gmail.

Comment: @SHAMe: You sound outraged as if your employer would have actually accessed these data. But, all what was described is that (due to your error) it would have been technically possible - which is usually far away from actually happening.

Comment: i hope so Steffen. These are really personal information (nothing illegal though)